# Is there an online user agent database?

Tags: web-services, web-applications, user-agent

How do you parse your user agent strings? I'm looking to get:

- Browser
- Browser Version
- OS
- OS Version

from a user agent string. My app is written in perl and was previously using [HTTP::BrowserDetect](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::BrowserDetect). It's a bit dated and is no longer maintained. (Edit: it's since been updated.) I'm in no way tied to using perl for the actual lookup.

I've come to the conclusion that automagic parsing is a lost cause. I was thinking of writing a crud type app to show me a list of unclassified UA's and manually keep them up to date.

Does such an resource already exist that I can tap into? It would be awesome if I could make an HTTP call to look up the user agent info.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for mobile phones? If so, there is deviceatlas.com ... if not, disregard :)

Comment: I've integrated a lot of Online Databases in this abstraction layer, maybe you can use it compare them https://github.com/ThaDafinser/UserAgentParser#providers

Comment: Mozilla has a good list of User-Agent detection libraries here: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Compatibility/UADetectionLibraries

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[useragentstring.com](http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php) has browser and OS information for its user agent strings. There's also an 'analyze' box to submit your own string. I don't know how easy it is to hook up to automatically, but it seems to have the sort of info you want.

**Update from Original Posting (don't want to steal your upvotes):**

I got this back from the author of http://useragentstring.com/:

> I have a simple API, but I'm about to
> recode a lot of my site, so it might
> change in the near future. If you link
> to my site, you can send a
> useragentstring in a form field or in
> the querystring with the name 'uas':
>
> http://www.useragentstring.com/?uas=Opera/9.70%20(Linux%20i686%20;%20U;%20en-us)%20Presto/2.2.0
>
> this will automatically parse the
> string. if you add &getText=all
>
> http://www.useragentstring.com/?uas=Opera/9.70%20(Linux%20i686%20;%20U;%20en-us)%20Presto/2.2.0&getText=all
>
> you will get a text file with key
> value pairs like
> agent_type=Browser;agent_name=Opera;agent_version=9.70...

Comment: I've sent an email to the author to see if I can query his service, or download a static database. It seems like the best one so far.

Comment: This site appears to be gone.

Comment: Does not contain information about any recent Windows releases and shows them as Windows NT.

Comment: is it possible to get em all?

Comment: The site is gone.

Comment: Sad to say, I tried accessing useragentstring.com today and it's not loading. Used it before and it's a great resource.

Comment: The non-HTML version is **still working**: http://www.useragentstring.com/?uas=Opera/9.70%20(Linux%20i686%20;%20U;%20en-us)%20Presto/2.2.0&getText=all

Answer (score 4):

## Browser Capabilities Project

> The browscap.ini file is a database which provides a lot of details
> about browsers and their capabilities, such as name, versions,
> Javascript support and so on.
>
> The browscap.ini, which provides a lot of details about browsers and
> their capabilities, such as name, versions, Javascript support and so
> on.
>
> PHP's native get_browser() function parses this file and provides you
> with a complete set of information about every browser's details, But
> it requires the path to the browscap.ini file to be specified in the
> php.ini browscap directive which is flagged as PHP_INI_SYSTEM.

http://browscap.org/

Comment: I've found that only the "lite" version of browscap is worth using, the other two larger files add too much overhead. My solution is to start with browscap lite .ini, which is successful about 95% of the time, and if that doesn't work (get_browser() returns "defaultProperties"), then use an online api service like [whatismybrowser](https://github.com/whatismybrowser/api-sample-php-5)

Comment: It is the best solution I've seen so far.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. http://www.user-agents.org/

Comment: -1 This doesn't break down versions/OS's and there are no matches for any of the records in my database.

Comment: Have you tried Google Analytics? It won't do bots & spiders that don't process javascript but you'll get almost all your human users tracked.

Answer (score 3):

I was looking for a searchable list of UA's.  user-agents.org is searchable, but didn't have nearly enough data.  I found http://www.botsvsbrowsers.com/.  It is cluttered with ads, but there's a search bar on the right side that was exactly was I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

This thread is a few years old but here is a new resource in search for user agents: [ua.theafh.net](http://ua.theafh.net/) with 5.4 million agents. You could for example filter for browsers and use wildcard search: http://ua.theafh.net/list.php?s=%22%2A%22&include=yes&class=abr&do=desc - there is also the possibility to download search results as CSV

Answer (score 2):

I found this JSON-encoded list of spiders/bots https://github.com/monperrus/crawler-user-agents appears to be regularly updated as of 2017.

Comment: It's Syntactic and not real data.

Comment: @MelroyvandenBerg not sure what you think is missing, but keep in mind that it was a simple list when I posted my answer in 2017.

Comment: So looking at https://github.com/monperrus/crawler-user-agents/blob/master/crawler-user-agents.json, shows me a list of web scrapers user-agent strings from Google, Yahoo etc. Which is fine I guess, but these are not the user-agent  strings from real web browsers for example, if you want to mimic a "real" user.

Answer (score 1):

Most updated resource in 2017:

https://techblog.willshouse.com/2012/01/03/most-common-user-agents/

They also provide their list in TXT format.

Answer (score 1):

We have a huge database of user agents, organised by Software, Operating System, Platform, Hardware Type, Software Type and Rendering Engine:

https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/useragents/explore/

All the other user agent listings do a pretty average job of making it easy to browse related user agents, so when I built this listing, making this easy for users was one of the major priorities behind the design of it.

You can also sign up for the free API which will give you access to our User Agent Parser.

https://developers.whatismybrowser.com/api/

Comment: @whatismybrowser-com is there a way I can supply the user agent in the URL so that I could create a link to your site with an already populated User Agent string to parse? I understand there is an API, but I just want to link to your site with a specific string

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://botopedia.org. It also offers IP validation that helps prevent spoofing.

Answer (score 0):

Since you posted your question, [HTTP::BrowserDetect](https://metacpan.org/pod/HTTP::BrowserDetect) has since been updated. Once installed, here's how you could use it to parse a text file of user-agent strings:

```
cat user_agent_strings.txt | perl -nE 'use HTTP::BrowserDetect; $ua =  HTTP::BrowserDetect->new($_); say $ua->browser_string || "unknown";'
```