# How do I countermeasure image hotlinking protection with Curl? I need to download these images

Tags: php, .htaccess, curl

Suppose the image's access is hotlinking-protected (for example by htaccess or by some other way because I have no clue) and hence, I can not access it directly in my browsers address bar via the URL verbatim (e.g.  `http://example.com/images/test.jpg`).

But if loaded through `img` tag in my browser-window and with relative path
 (`<img src="/images/test.jpg" />` inside the HTML) the image is visible on the page.

So, I wanted to ask if it is possible to make a request though CURL to get that image? I use PHP.

This question does not solve the problem [php curl: how can i emulate a get request exactly like a web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440729/php-curl-how-can-i-emulate-a-get-request-exactly-like-a-web-browser)

Comment: Loading using `img` tag **is** a direct access. If it's possible to retrieve it with browser - it's possible to retrieve it with CURL

Comment: Do not ask if something is possible. Show us what you've tried so far and tell us what your problem is with that.

Comment: @zerkms I updated the question I made a little mistake in it, actually the path is relative in `img` tag. In this case is it considered a direct access ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to define a referer. A referer is not send if you input the url directly but it will be send (on default settings) when you link it.

For php:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, 'http://stackoverflow.com/a/16383495/995926');
```

Comment: 2 points: 1. It will make issues for valid users 2. Bad guys with CURL will still be able to send a referrer and download an image

Comment: @zerkms IMHO is is not possible to secure content in the www. It is always public... Except with some kind of auth systems.

Comment: yep, that's right ;-) That's why your answer at the moment isn't helpful for the OP ;-)

Comment: I understood the question in this way: *How can I download that image? It works for me in a html page, but not directly.* I think my answer sloves that problem...

Comment: hm...... that's another point, I see now. My original though was - that OP is the service owner, who wants to protect his images. Hmmmmm

Comment: @zerkms: maybe the OP is a bad guy with cURL? `;-)`

Comment: @halfer: yea, I am the bad guy :D

Comment: @Davo: do something good today, to balance out your karma!

Comment: @halfer I do not believe in karma ;) IMHO our life is just the result of our thoughts, nothing more

Comment: @halfer: answerer's karma got worse as well actually