# simple html dom url length error

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

```
<?php
include('../simple_html_dom.php');

$fname = "http://www.myurl.com";

$html = file_get_html($fname);

$divs = $html->find('h6');
foreach($divs as $element)
{
 $title = $element->find('a', 0)->plaintext;
 echo $title.'<br>';
}
echo '<br>';
?>
```

I got this error:

> "failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error in......."

My url is very length, its actual length is 750 characters.
if I use wget it show "file name too long"

How can I fix it? I need it to work with simple dom

Comment: Does your URL works in a legitimate browser?

Comment: Yes it working all browser...I added my url pls check

Comment: Then that's probably the server refusing to serve your request because of User-Agent or something. Do you control the server for this URL?

Comment: How can i check it with my server?

Comment: The URL does not work in my browser either.

Comment: Url working fine in my browser

Comment: That's strange. I tried with both Chrome and FF and your link results in a 500 error (whereas my link works in both of them).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

750 characters is OK for an URL length. The practical limit most often used is 2000 chars, which is the limit in older IEs.

You should try to emulate a web browser making the request. See [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440729/php-curl-how-can-i-emulate-a-get-request-exactly-like-a-web-browser).

Edit: Using CURL with your code

```
<?php

// include is not a function, don't use parens (also use require instead)
require '../simple_html_dom.php';

$fname = "http://www.myurl.com";

$agent= 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
// don't want to polute your output
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fname);
$result=curl_exec($ch);

$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load($result);

$divs = $html->find('h6');
foreach($divs as $element)
{
 $title = $element->find('a', 0)->plaintext;
 echo $title.'<br>';
}
echo '<br>';
```

Comment: But youtubeonfire.com will serve will `file_get_html`. So no need to try this solution...

Comment: Thank you ... Problem is... that url changed link with every ip... it work fine with my localhost.. not work same link with my another apache server. thank u

Answer (score 0):

The URL length is fine. The link is probably broken or has expired.
I tried with the link shown below and the results seem fine:

```
<?php
include("simple_html_dom.php");

$fname = "http://www.youtubeonfire.com/?genre=0&language=0&next_token=rO0ABXNyACdjb20uYW1hem9uLnNkcy5RdWVyeVByb2Nlc3Nvci5Nb3JlVG9rZW7racXLnINNqwMA%0AC0kAFGluaXRpYWxDb25qdW5jdEluZGV4WgAOaXNQYWdlQm91bmRhcnlKAAxsYXN0RW50aXR5SURa%0AAApscnFFbmFibGVkSQAPcXVlcnlDb21wbGV4aXR5SgATcXVlcnlTdHJpbmdDaGVja3N1bUkACnVu%0AaW9uSW5kZXhaAA11c2VRdWVyeUluZGV4TAANY29uc2lzdGVudExTTnQAEkxqYXZhL2xhbmcvU3Ry%0AaW5nO0wAEmxhc3RBdHRyaWJ1dGVWYWx1ZXEAfgABTAAJc29ydE9yZGVydAAvTGNvbS9hbWF6b24v%0Ac2RzL1F1ZXJ5UHJvY2Vzc29yL1F1ZXJ5JFNvcnRPcmRlcjt4cAAAAAEAAAAAAAABds0AAAAAAQAA%0AAAC71ED7AAAAAAFwdAAQMDAwMDAwMDAwMDAwMjAxM35yAC1jb20uYW1hem9uLnNkcy5RdWVyeVBy%0Ab2Nlc3Nvci5RdWVyeSRTb3J0T3JkZXIAAAAAAAAAABIAAHhyAA5qYXZhLmxhbmcuRW51bQAAAAAA%0AAAAAEgAAeHB0AApERVNDRU5ESU5HeA%3D%3D&sort=2";

$html = file_get_html($fname);

$divs = $html->find("h6");
foreach($divs as $element) {
    $title = $element->find("a", 0)->plaintext;
    echo($title . "<br />");
}
echo("<br />");
```

Output:

```
Spider (2013)
500 MPH STORM 2013 HD
Van Diemans Land (Action,Adventure,20...
Good Agent is A Bad Agent (Full HQ En...
Employee of the Month (Full HQ Englis...
The Croods (2013)
GIRLFRIENDS - 2013
Boys Are Pigs-2013
The Patriot -2013
My Daughter&#x27;s Secret -2013
Dead on Arrival [2013]
Flght 2013XViD1
Samsung Galaxy S4 Presentation UNPACK...
Affinity 2013
Golden Globe Awards 2013: Full Show
Parker-2013
Hells&#x27; Kitchen-  New Action Movie 2013
ALIENS [2013]
7 Nights Of Darkness -2013
Hansel And Gretel 2013
The Collection (2012)
Mac And Devin Go To High School 2012
Red Dawn (2012)
Hijacked -2012
Bending The Rules -2012
Inside -2012
VAMPIRELAND-2012
Dead Mine -2012
Devil Seed-2012
Kill Em All -2012
One In The Chamber -2012
The Forger - 2012
Dark Desire -2012
A Common Man -2012 .
The Helpers -2012
Red Dawn- 2012 720p
```

So, fix the problem with the URL and everything will work just fine !

Comment: Double-check your link. Are you sure it is working (right now) from a browser ?

Answer (score 0):

You say your URL is working in your browser, while all of us here receive a 500 error, like your script does.

The site probably check the token in the URL against the IP and possibly other headers of the request. So you need to find a way to get a tokenized URL from your PHP script.

For that, you need to first download main page **from you PHP script**, then find the next link's URL and use this one in your script.