# file_get_contents is not working for some url

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I use `file_get_contents` in PHP. In the below code in first URL works fine but the second one isn't working.

```
$URL = "http://test6473.blogspot.com";
$domain = file_get_contents($URL);
print_r($domain);


$add_url= "http://adfoc.us/1575051";
$add_domain = file_get_contents($add_url);
echo $add_domain;
```

Any suggestions on why the second one doesn't work?

Comment: So what is the second url actually echoing? Or are you getting any error messages?

Comment: What do you mean "not working" ?

Comment: please open both url in browser. Both returning HTML page.

Comment: maybe, they blocked non browser requests :P

Comment: @DBK if so then, is there any other option to do this?

Comment: Is there a way to actually achieve this using file_get_contents instead of curl?

Comment: @SergioA. I don't think so far any way to do so.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

URL which is not retrieved by file_get_contents, because their server checks whether the request come from browser or any script. If they found request from script they simply disable page contents.

So that I have to make a request similar as browser request. So I have used following code to get 2nd url contents. It might be different for different web server. Because they might keep different checks.

Even though why dont you try to use following code! If you are lucky this might work for you!!

```
function getUrlContent($url) {
    fopen("cookies.txt", "w");
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    $host = $parts['host'];
    $ch = curl_init();
    $header = array('GET /1575051 HTTP/1.1',
        "Host: {$host}",
        'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8',
        'Cache-Control:max-age=0',
        'Connection:keep-alive',
        'Host:adfoc.us',
        'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36',
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIESESSION, true);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, 'cookies.txt');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

$url = "http://adfoc.us/1575051";
$html = getUrlContent($url);
```

Thanks everyone for the guidance.

Comment: And also I want to mention that file get_contents does not start any session or set cookies which generally done by curl/browsers.

Comment: is it necessary `cookies.txt` file should be there?

Comment: @hnn It is necessary only when `URL` which you want to call maintain any cookie in browser.

Comment: This worked for me when I was getting no response from a call to Google maps using something like http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=AL2&sensor=false&components=country:UK

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it looks like the second site blocks access from unrecognized browsers. Even using curl from the command line doesn't work:

```
curl -I http://adfoc.us/1575051
```

gives:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: cloudflare-nginx
Date: Fri, 28 Jun 2013 12:15:40 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.0
Set-Cookie: __cfduid=d7cd1bf18c136a288cc2b36065a3b31f01372421740; expires=Mon, 23-Dec-2019 23:50:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.adfoc.us
CF-RAY: 85a4dc6829e06d0
```

but no content. Note it returns status 200 so if you check the returned string for boolean === false to see if it failed, it will actually appear as if it has worked.

If you need to spoof the useragent (and possibly other things) to try and get the url to accept your request, you'll need to take the plunge with the curl libraries and try different combinations to try and get it working. Experimenting to see what works with the curl command line first would also be a good way to reduce development time in investigating this.

Here's someone who has been through this before:

[php curl: how can i emulate a get request exactly like a web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440729/php-curl-how-can-i-emulate-a-get-request-exactly-like-a-web-browser)

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have tried given url of aonther answer. But still its not working. :(

Comment: Unfortunately every web site is different - you may need to experiment with a variety of different http headers before you get one which the website accepts... or it may just never work... or you may even need cookie support spoofing. Unfortunately trial and error is all you can do here - this sort of stuff is getting increasingly difficult to do :(

Answer (score 1):

looks like the second url answers too slow sometimes, maybe have redirects.
try to use curl and set bigger timeout.
also, turn errors on

```
error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors','On');
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code also

```php
<?php

function getUrlContent($url) {
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    $host = $parts['host'];
    $ch = curl_init();
    $header = array('GET /1575051 HTTP/1.1',
        "Host: {$host}",
        'Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
        'Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8',
        'Cache-Control:max-age=0',
        'Connection:keep-alive',
        'Host:adfoc.us',
        'User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_8_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/27.0.1453.116 Safari/537.36',
    );

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $result;
}

$url = "https://news.google.com/rss/search?q=apple&hl=en-IN&gl=IN&ceid=IN:en";
$html = getUrlContent($url);

$xml = simplexml_load_string($html);
$json = json_encode($xml);
$array = json_decode($json,TRUE);


print_r($array);
?>
```