# get data from URL using file_get_contents and cURL

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, file-get-contents

I am using `codeigniter` framework.

I want to retrieve the data from the **URL** provided. I already tried this answers: [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617512/get-json-object-from-url).

Problem is that when i access the url that time it is printing the data. but when i try it with `file_get_contents` function, it is not going to print any data.

```
<?php
$url ='https://test.com/getSessionData';
$test = file_get_contents($url);
$t = json_decode($test);
var_dump($t);
?>
```

That url returns **json data** like:

```
{
    "email": "test@t.com",
    "LOGIN": true,
    "name": "testing",
    "logintype": "ca"
}
```

Also tried using **cURL**:

```
<?php
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
$curl_jason = json_decode($curl_response, true);
print_r($curl_jason);
?>
```

But it is **not working** and it returns empty. i have checked that `allow_url_fopen` is `on`.

Comment: Add the code of the file `'https://test.com/getSessionData'`

Comment: @bIgBoY please check my updated question

Comment: Hit directly `https://test.com/getSessionData` to your browse and check what it return

Comment: @Saty it returns: `{
    "email": "test@t.com",
    "LOGIN": true,
    "name": "testing",
    "logintype": "ca"
}`

Comment: Does that URL require any state or session to get response?

Comment: @Parixit yes.. it requires the session to be set..

Comment: @hnn Then kindly check http://stackoverflow.com/a/17376952/631652 or you can use `CURL` as it maintain session.

Comment: @Parixit what i did is, i open 1 tabs, in one tab i logged in and in another tab i am printing that session `URL`, so in second tab it should print data, but not printing..

Comment: @Parixit i also tried `cURL` but not working, let me check link you given.. and get back..

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1975461/how-to-get-file-get-contents-work-with-https

Comment: @Saty i am getting this `openssl: yes http wrapper: yes https wrapper: yes `

Answer (score -1):

This is the class I said:

```
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: rain
 * Date: 15/11/2
 * Time: 下午4:08
 */
class MyCurlLibrary{
    public static function getRequest($url,Array $data=array(),$isNeedHeader=0){
        $ch = curl_init();
        if($data){
            $bindQuery = http_build_query($data);
            $url.="?".$bindQuery;
        }
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        //if need return
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        //this is for https
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, $isNeedHeader);//if contains header 
        //this is for web redirect problem
        //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        return $output;
    }

    public static function postRequest($url,Array $data=array()){
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        // post Data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        // post variable
        if($data){
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        }
        $output = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        //return data
        return $output;
    }

}

/**
 * sample
 *
 * //test Data
    $url = "http://localhost:8080/test/test.php";//改文件有代码  print_r($_GET);         print_r($_POST)
    $data = array('a'=>'b','c'=>'d',8=>666,888);
    //test get function
    $result = MyCurl::getRequest($url,$data);
    //test post function
    $result = MyCurl::postRequest($url,$data);
    //print result
    var_dump($result);
 *
 *
 */
```

Comment: using phpinfo() to see if you have that extension.If not,try <a href="http://php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php">install it</a>

Comment: Sorry for the format,I can't make it correct in comment.What's your OS,linux /Mac or Win?

Comment: Then I  think you can use curl instead.Here is a class I used,you can try if you need,I'll add it in the answer.

Comment: can you please change the comments' language in your answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98068/discussion-between-rain-and-hnn).

Answer (score -1):

This might helpful

http://php.net/manual/en/migration56.openssl.php

So code looks like this:

```
<?php

$arrContextOptions=array(
    "ssl"=>array(
        "cafile" => "/path/to/bundle/ca-bundle.crt",
        "verify_peer"=>false,
        "verify_peer_name"=>false,
    ),
);


$response = file_get_contents("https://test.com/getSessionData", false, stream_context_create($arrContextOptions));

echo $response; ?>
```

Comment: what should be in `cafile`?

Comment: Path to your ssl certificate file

Comment: i don't know where is it