# cURL check if text exists on website

Tags: php, curl

Trying to see if an IG acc is used or free but it always return false even if the account exists...

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init("http://www.instagram.com/asd9usa0d0sad90sa90a09d");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$text = curl_exec($ch);
$test = strpos($text, "Sorry, this page");

print_r($text);

if ($test==false)
{
    echo "Username exists";
}
else
{
    echo "Username does not exist";
}

?>
```

If an IG acc doesn't exist, example instagram.com/basdlkasld4 then it will disaplay "Sorry, this page isn't available.".

Comment: When your php is executted, what is the value of: `$text`.... Echo it as well, and check yourself what is that you are receiving. It can be that your string is encoded as something else than the page, and the needle is never found.

Comment: If I do $print_r($text) and set URL to google.com then google.com shows up in the browser. But when I enter instagram.com it doesn't work. I have tried with and without www, http, https...

Comment: That is not what is relevant here. The point is, a cURL request is different from a Browser request. It is possible that the Server is replying with something other than `HTTP OK (200)`, it is possible that is replying with other content, it is possible that the Server expects user agents, etc... Too many possibilities. I myself preffer [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) to query other sites. Check documentation on building the Header for your query.

Comment: I did follow this exact "guide" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440729/php-curl-how-can-i-emulate-a-get-request-exactly-like-a-web-browser to mimic a browser. Still does not work nor display the website when I echo it!

Answer (score 1):

That URL redirects a couple of times before reaching the **Sorry, this page...** result. If you add the following line, Curl will follow the redirects correctly.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

Comment: I can't edit my post... But I added that line and it still always return "Username exists.".

Comment: Not sure what else to suggest, it works fine here with that line added.

Comment: Its something with instagram.com. If I do $print_($text) and set URL to google.com then google.com shows up in the browser. But when I enter instagram.com it doesn't work. I have tried with and without www, http, https...