# HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden with "Call to a member function find() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php"

Tags: php, curl, dom

I want to extract data from a website but I'm getting a warning.

```
    <?php
        include("simple_html_dom.php");
        $html = file_get_html("https://ffs-gaming.com/clans.php?clanid=1264");
        $title = $html->find("div.number", 0)->innertext;
        echo $title;
    ?>
```

With other websites it works very well but it doesn't with this one.
I'm getting that warning.

> Warning: file_get_contents(https://ffs-gaming.com/clans.php?clanid=1264): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden in C:\xampp\htdocs\simple_html_dom.php on line 75
>
> Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on boolean in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 12

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Really don't see the point in _Community Bot_ bumping these ancient questions. Voting to close as _"Needs more focus"_. The API obviously needs credentials

Answer (score -1):

They probably only allow real browser requests.

Try to emulate a browser using cUrl:

[php curl: how can i emulate a get request exactly like a web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440729/php-curl-how-can-i-emulate-a-get-request-exactly-like-a-web-browser)