# Save image using cURL

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

This is an URL that points to an image:

> https://www.somesite.com/some/dir/jsp/data.jsp?KEY=12155&TYPE=jpg&qi=R7SWtM5F5PL4cDDFfdfpIrqIWSY3gr2XGQg=

I get the image if I use cURL as this command in CLI:

`/usr/bin/curl -o 1234.jpg 'the_url_to_image'`

I need to use cURL in PHP with arguments.
I tried several parameters to get the image, and I always get a 403 error

> Access to the specified resource has been forbidden. Apache Tomcat

My parameters (only the cURL parameters, the code for writting the image to file is not here):

```
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $img_url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36');
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,$cookie_filename);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE,$cookie_filename);
 $page_content  = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
```

**EDIT**

If I feed the image URL to this page:

> onlinecurl.com

I get the image binary back, and no the error message.

So the image can be saved with cURL, I only need to get the  `curl_setopt` settings right.

**EDIT**

By running the a command in CLI the image is saved to the local path

`/usr/bin/curl -o 1234.jpg 'the_url_to_image'`

When running the same command with

`shell_exec("/usr/bin/curl -o 1234.jpg 'the_url_to_image'")`

The error message is saved in the 1234.jpg file.

What can be the difference in the command line and code execution of the same command?

Comment: Maybe something like `file_put_contents('save path here', file_get_contents('url here', 'create curl stream context here'))`

Comment: @user3783243 I get the same 403 error for the `file_get_contents('image_url')`

Comment: use curl_file_create function 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/curlfile.construct.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out the problem was a simple one.

-The first clue was that the command in terminal was working but the same command with `shell_exec()` was returning an error.

-The second clue was that as delboy1978uk mentioned the error was not 401 *not authenticated* but a 403 *non authorized*.

So there had to be a problem with the URL or parameter.
I printed out the URL but found no error....
So long story short, the problem was with the special characters in the URL. When I printed the URL the browser displayed the `&` character correctly not as the function got it as a parameter `&amp;`.

So if I feed URL to `htmlspecialchars_decode()` prior to run the command then it works flawlessly.

**So lookout for special characters in the URL!**

Answer (score 1):

> What can be the difference in the command line and code execution of the same command ?

your user-agent isn't even close:

> curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.79 Safari/537.36');

try setting it to a real curl-cli useragent, like

> curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'curl/7.63.0');

or

> curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'curl/'.(curl_version()['version']));

it's rare, but it's possible (and even likely given the evidence) that they're using a user-agent whitelist, and Google Chrome (or is it Safari?) is not on their whitelist, but curl-cli is...

another possible explanation is that they're trying to detect and block people **lying** on their user-agent, and it's easy to detect that you're lying: you're (falsely) saying that you are Safari or Chrome, and both of those always sends `Acccept-Encoding: gzip/deflate/whatever`, but your curl request does not (because you didn't use CURLOPT_ENCODING), thus it's easy to detect that your user-agent is fake, maybe that's what's causing the block. either way, try using a real curl user-agent.

Comment: I tried to set the `CURLOPT_USERAGENT` to curl or to Mozzila and to set the `CURLOPT_ENCODING` but still not working .


Probably they have some protection for parsing, but the command line version is working, so there must be some setting I'm missing.

Comment: @Szekelygobe don't set it to mozilla, set it to `curl/7.63.0`

Comment: @Szekelygobe ... in that case, set up a netcat server like explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/55829622/1067003 and compare the difference between the curl cli program and the php script, what are their differences?

Comment: I tried to execute the `/usr/bin/curl -o 1234.jpg 'the_url_to_image'`  command with `shell_exec()`, failed to save the image, it returned the same error.

Comment: I tested the browser request with `netcat` and restructured the `cURL` request to exactly mimic the browser's request, but still no success...

Answer (score 1):

401 is Unauthorized

403 is Forbidden

These are badly described.

401 really means not *Authenticated*

403 really means not *Authorized*

If this is indeed a protected resource that requires being logged in to fetch it, then this means that yes, the server recognises you (you didn't get a 401), but you don't have the required permissions (403).

If, on the other, hand the image really is public, actually pasting the link could help us to help you.

Comment: make sure you include the query parameters, if you remove the last one from the url you get the 403

Comment: You saved the image ? I use the same url for cURL as in the previous comment. I get 403 each time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0);
```

If this doesn't work you have to add the Apache Tomcat 
 in your web.xml:

```
<login-config>
  <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
```

Comment: The server is using java and is out of my reach, I use php and don't have a web.xml file.