# Difference between HTTP request using cURL and a web browser?

Tags: http, curl, firefox, postman, ethernet

I am working on an HTTP server running on an embedded system. It uses an ethernet chip that seems to work well. But I am experiencing a weird behavior.

When I make a request using a web browser, for example, Firefox or even a command-line based browser like `links`, I get a correct response from the server every time. It also works well if using Postman for testing. However, if I use `cURL`, every other call will get `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`.

Is there any underlying difference between an application doing an HTTP request and a simpler command line tool doing the same?

Furthermore, from the server logs, I realized that:

- Firefox: receives all responses correctly, and there's only one socket connected per request.
- Links: receives all responses correctly, and there are two sockets connected per request.
- cURL: fails to receive a response every other call, and there's only one socket connected per request.
- Node.js with fetch: receives a response but fails after a few more calls, while using one socket only.
- Python with requests: fails to receive a response every other call, and there's only one socket connected per request.

cURL and Node.js: Note that I used the cURL and fetch commands provided by the Firefox network analyzer.

In order to get the very same response, I went to the network analyzer in Firefox and copied the HTTP request from there so that the exact same headers are used. I verified from the logs that the payload the server received is always the same when running Firefox and `cURL`.

What else could be affecting the behavior of the server? I am expecting a bug, but since the payload is the same, I am wondering what else could be different between and fully feature application and a command line or script utility doing a bare request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I emulate a get request exactly like a web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440729/how-can-i-emulate-a-get-request-exactly-like-a-web-browser)

Comment: read my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/55829622/1067003 :)

Comment: Both answers were good, and I used that. I went to the network inspector, copied the cURL from of the request, and cURL still fails every other request with `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`. From the server log I can see that Firefox is generating a full http request that finishes successfully, but the one using cURL does not. It could well be a bug in the HTTP server, but I want to elucidate if cURL is doing something different.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming there are some differences in [request headers](https://firefox-source-docs.mozilla.org/devtools-user/network_monitor/request_details/index.html) when calling with a browser.

curl doesn't give more information than the attached arguments.

If you have the capability to check the request by yourself on the destination server, you should print/log out the header information from different requests.

Comment: And many/all(?) shells required certain "syntax" chars (`&;!.?`etc) to be escaped or quoted. use `"https:/url.com?var=val;&etc..."`. Good luck

Comment: I still haven't solved the issue yet, but I must mention that this isn't the answer. I have used the exact same headers as in Firefox and the issue is still there.