# php curl - emulate a request like a browser

Tags: php, web-scraping, curl, firefox, browser

i am trying to retrieve the content of the following page with PHP Curl:

https://www.whitepages.com/name/Antonio-Dalesio

The problem is that the page recognize that the request does not come from a browser and it gives the following error:

`Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue`

How can i emulate a request like Firefox with PHP Curl?

My code:

```
$url="https://www.whitepages.com/name/Antonio-Dalesio";
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.1) Gecko/20061204 Firefox/2.0.0.1");
// You can add your GET or POST param

// Retrieving session ID 
$strCookie = 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . '; path=/';    

// We pass the sessionid of the browser within the curl request
curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $strCookie ); 

// We receive the answer as if we were the browser
$curl_response = curl_exec($curl);

return $curl_response;
```

I have tried my code and i receive the following error:

`Enable JavaScript and cookies to continue`

Comment: You would need a headless browser, most likely. cURL can't execute JavaScript

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I emulate a get request exactly like a web browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440729/how-can-i-emulate-a-get-request-exactly-like-a-web-browser)

Comment: you could execute javascript on server side if needed or simulate if that is the case, btw the `CURLOPT_COOKIE` itself just pass specified cookies over the request, they are not updated or added when the server request so, that might be the issue here

Comment: @ADyson unfortunately you need to execute javascript to get past the CloudFlare protection bullshit. but other than the cloudflare stuff, you can get the data with just DOMDocument + json_decode() in this case, see my code below

Comment: Just don't scrape HTML. Use an API.

Comment: @hanshenrik I wouldn't say it's BS - it's one part of a reasonable attempt to try and fend off bots/scrapers/DDOS etc, and try to get the target site only seen by actual eyeballs. And your solution doesn't use "just DOMDOcument + json_encode", it uses HeadlessChromium - a headless browser, as I originally suggested. So I'm not sure of the point of your reply?

Answer (score 1):

That page is protected by CloudFlare protection bullshit, which you need javascript to get past. Forget curl, you need a real web browser. for example with Chromium and the https://github.com/chrome-php/chrome library:

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

$factory = new HeadlessChromium\BrowserFactory('chromium-browser');
$browser = $factory->createBrowser([
    'noSandbox' => true,
    'headless' => true,
    'customFlags' => [
        '--disable-dev-shm-usage', // for docker
    ],
]);
$page = $browser->createPage();
$page->navigate('https://www.whitepages.com/name/Antonio-Dalesio')->waitForNavigation(
    \HeadlessChromium\Page::LOAD,
);
$html = $page->getHTML();
$dom = new \DOMDocument('', '');
@$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xp = new \DOMXPath($dom);
// <script type="application/ld+json">
$js = $xp->query('//script[@type="application/ld+json"]')->item(0)->textContent;
$data = json_decode($js, true, 999, JSON_THROW_ON_ERROR);
var_export($data, false);
```

prints

```php
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    '@context' => 'http://schema.org',
    '@type' => 'Person',
    'name' => 'Antonio Dalesio',
    'givenName' => 'Antonio',
    'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
    'additionalName' => NULL,
    'URL' => '/name/Antonio-Dalesio/Youngstown-OH/PN3VzweYkm3',
    'homeLocation' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Place',
        'address' => 
        array (
          '@type' => 'PostalAddress',
          'addressLocality' => 'Youngstown',
          'addressRegion' => 'OH',
          'addressCountry' => 'US',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'telephone' => '(330) XXX-XXXX',
    'relatedTo' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Dino Mario Dalesio',
        'givenName' => 'Dino',
        'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
        'additionalName' => 'Mario',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Debra Ann Dalesio',
        'givenName' => 'Debra',
        'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
        'additionalName' => 'Ann',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Carol Louise Dalesio',
        'givenName' => 'Carol',
        'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
        'additionalName' => 'Louise',
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Carmen C Dalesio',
        'givenName' => 'Carmen',
        'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
        'additionalName' => 'C',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    '@context' => 'http://schema.org',
    '@type' => 'Person',
    'name' => 'Antonio D Dalesio',
    'givenName' => 'Antonio',
    'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
    'additionalName' => 'D',
    'URL' => '/name/Antonio-D-Dalesio/Dyer-IN/PA8mLDAbYP3',
    'homeLocation' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Place',
        'address' => 
        array (
          '@type' => 'PostalAddress',
          'addressLocality' => 'Dyer',
          'addressRegion' => 'IN',
          'addressCountry' => 'US',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'telephone' => '(219) XXX-XXXX',
    'relatedTo' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Caterina D Dalesio',
        'givenName' => 'Caterina',
        'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
        'additionalName' => 'D',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Shannon Marie Wilson',
        'givenName' => 'Shannon',
        'familyName' => 'Wilson',
        'additionalName' => 'Marie',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Nico Dalesio',
        'givenName' => 'Nico',
        'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
        'additionalName' => NULL,
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Katya D Alesio',
        'givenName' => 'Katya',
        'familyName' => 'Alesio',
        'additionalName' => 'D',
      ),
      4 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Nicola D Dalesio',
        'givenName' => 'Nicola',
        'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
        'additionalName' => 'D',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    '@context' => 'http://schema.org',
    '@type' => 'Person',
    'name' => 'Antonio Dalesio',
    'givenName' => 'Antonio',
    'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
    'additionalName' => NULL,
    'URL' => '/name/Antonio-Dalesio/League-City-TX/Pd96ROrjNn9',
    'homeLocation' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Place',
        'address' => 
        array (
          '@type' => 'PostalAddress',
          'addressLocality' => 'League City',
          'addressRegion' => 'TX',
          'addressCountry' => 'US',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'telephone' => '(XXX) XXX-XXXX',
    'relatedTo' => 
    array (
    ),
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    '@context' => 'http://schema.org',
    '@type' => 'Person',
    'name' => 'Antonio P Dalesio',
    'givenName' => 'Antonio',
    'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
    'additionalName' => 'P',
    'URL' => '/name/Antonio-P-Dalesio/Hockessin-DE/PG9RlDZYzZ3',
    'homeLocation' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Place',
        'address' => 
        array (
          '@type' => 'PostalAddress',
          'addressLocality' => 'Hockessin',
          'addressRegion' => 'DE',
          'addressCountry' => 'US',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'telephone' => '(302) XXX-XXXX',
    'relatedTo' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Marika P Dalesio',
        'givenName' => 'Marika',
        'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
        'additionalName' => 'P',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Stefania Difreca Panza',
        'givenName' => 'Stefania',
        'familyName' => 'Panza',
        'additionalName' => 'Difreca',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Carlo Dalesio',
        'givenName' => 'Carlo',
        'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
        'additionalName' => NULL,
      ),
    ),
  ),
  4 => 
  array (
    '@context' => 'http://schema.org',
    '@type' => 'Person',
    'name' => 'Anthony M Dalesio',
    'givenName' => 'Anthony',
    'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
    'additionalName' => 'M',
    'URL' => '/name/Anthony-M-Dalesio/Coraopolis-PA/PbyPWOlXP29',
    'homeLocation' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Place',
        'address' => 
        array (
          '@type' => 'PostalAddress',
          'addressLocality' => 'Coraopolis',
          'addressRegion' => 'PA',
          'addressCountry' => 'US',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'telephone' => '(412) XXX-XXXX',
    'relatedTo' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Angela D Dalesio',
        'givenName' => 'Angela',
        'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
        'additionalName' => 'D',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Stephen James Dalesio',
        'givenName' => 'Stephen',
        'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
        'additionalName' => 'James',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  5 => 
  array (
    '@context' => 'http://schema.org',
    '@type' => 'Person',
    'name' => 'Anthony Dalesio',
    'givenName' => 'Anthony',
    'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
    'additionalName' => NULL,
    'URL' => '/name/Anthony-Dalesio/Tyrone-PA/Pe9x2nNpgW3',
    'homeLocation' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Place',
        'address' => 
        array (
          '@type' => 'PostalAddress',
          'addressLocality' => 'Tyrone',
          'addressRegion' => 'PA',
          'addressCountry' => 'US',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'telephone' => '(XXX) XXX-XXXX',
    'relatedTo' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Lorenzo J Dalesio',
        'givenName' => 'Lorenzo',
        'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
        'additionalName' => 'J',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  6 => 
  array (
    '@context' => 'http://schema.org',
    '@type' => 'Person',
    'name' => 'Anthony P Dalesio',
    'givenName' => 'Anthony',
    'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
    'additionalName' => 'P',
    'URL' => '/name/Anthony-P-Dalesio/Weirton-WV/Pl8aDbgEE3b',
    'homeLocation' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Place',
        'address' => 
        array (
          '@type' => 'PostalAddress',
          'addressLocality' => 'Weirton',
          'addressRegion' => 'WV',
          'addressCountry' => 'US',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'telephone' => '(304) XXX-XXXX',
    'relatedTo' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Nicole A Dalesio',
        'givenName' => 'Nicole',
        'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
        'additionalName' => 'A',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Charlotte E Dalesio',
        'givenName' => 'Charlotte',
        'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
        'additionalName' => 'E',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Marsha C Needy',
        'givenName' => 'Marsha',
        'familyName' => 'Needy',
        'additionalName' => 'C',
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Carmela D Alesio',
        'givenName' => 'Carmela',
        'familyName' => 'Alesio',
        'additionalName' => 'D',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  7 => 
  array (
    '@context' => 'http://schema.org',
    '@type' => 'Person',
    'name' => 'Anthony J Dalesio',
    'givenName' => 'Anthony',
    'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
    'additionalName' => 'J',
    'URL' => '/name/Anthony-J-Dalesio/Willingboro-NJ/Pk9AxD64o8A',
    'homeLocation' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Place',
        'address' => 
        array (
          '@type' => 'PostalAddress',
          'addressLocality' => 'Willingboro',
          'addressRegion' => 'NJ',
          'addressCountry' => 'US',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'telephone' => '(609) XXX-XXXX',
    'relatedTo' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Veronica Canonigo Dalesio',
        'givenName' => 'Veronica',
        'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
        'additionalName' => 'Canonigo',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Jacquelin M McCann',
        'givenName' => 'Jacquelin',
        'familyName' => 'McCann',
        'additionalName' => 'M',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Margaret M Dalesio',
        'givenName' => 'Margaret',
        'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
        'additionalName' => 'M',
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Michael D Dalesio',
        'givenName' => 'Michael',
        'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
        'additionalName' => 'D',
      ),
      4 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Michael R Dalesio',
        'givenName' => 'Michael',
        'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
        'additionalName' => 'R',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  8 => 
  array (
    '@context' => 'http://schema.org',
    '@type' => 'Person',
    'name' => 'Anthony N Dalesio',
    'givenName' => 'Anthony',
    'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
    'additionalName' => 'N',
    'URL' => '/name/Anthony-N-Dalesio/Baldwin-NY/PE3EXoPOvyB',
    'homeLocation' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Place',
        'address' => 
        array (
          '@type' => 'PostalAddress',
          'addressLocality' => 'Baldwin',
          'addressRegion' => 'NY',
          'addressCountry' => 'US',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'telephone' => '(718) XXX-XXXX',
    'relatedTo' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Sean M Lynch',
        'givenName' => 'Sean',
        'familyName' => 'Lynch',
        'additionalName' => 'M',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Patricia Ann Dalesio',
        'givenName' => 'Patricia',
        'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
        'additionalName' => 'Ann',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Maureen P Mullaney',
        'givenName' => 'Maureen',
        'familyName' => 'Mullaney',
        'additionalName' => 'P',
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Patricia A Morgera',
        'givenName' => 'Patricia',
        'familyName' => 'Morgera',
        'additionalName' => 'A',
      ),
      4 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Nicole M Dalesio',
        'givenName' => 'Nicole',
        'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
        'additionalName' => 'M',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  9 => 
  array (
    '@context' => 'http://schema.org',
    '@type' => 'Person',
    'name' => 'Anthony T Dalesio',
    'givenName' => 'Anthony',
    'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
    'additionalName' => 'T',
    'URL' => '/name/Anthony-T-Dalesio/Hatfield-PA/Pl3lmaeRl8E',
    'homeLocation' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Place',
        'address' => 
        array (
          '@type' => 'PostalAddress',
          'addressLocality' => 'Hatfield',
          'addressRegion' => 'PA',
          'addressCountry' => 'US',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'telephone' => '(215) XXX-XXXX',
    'relatedTo' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Susan M Dalesio',
        'givenName' => 'Susan',
        'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
        'additionalName' => 'M',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Amie Jennifer Natali',
        'givenName' => 'Amie',
        'familyName' => 'Natali',
        'additionalName' => 'Jennifer',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  10 => 
  array (
    '@context' => 'http://schema.org',
    '@type' => 'Person',
    'name' => 'Anthony C Dalesio',
    'givenName' => 'Anthony',
    'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
    'additionalName' => 'C',
    'URL' => '/name/Anthony-C-Dalesio/Broadview-Heights-OH/PvyBGdBJka3',
    'homeLocation' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Place',
        'address' => 
        array (
          '@type' => 'PostalAddress',
          'addressLocality' => 'Broadview Heights',
          'addressRegion' => 'OH',
          'addressCountry' => 'US',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'telephone' => '(440) XXX-XXXX',
    'relatedTo' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Everett W Dalesio',
        'givenName' => 'Everett',
        'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
        'additionalName' => 'W',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Emery George Dalesio',
        'givenName' => 'Emery',
        'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
        'additionalName' => 'George',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Emery P Dalesio',
        'givenName' => 'Emery',
        'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
        'additionalName' => 'P',
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Kathleen M Dalesio',
        'givenName' => 'Kathleen',
        'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
        'additionalName' => 'M',
      ),
      4 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Judy E Viancourt',
        'givenName' => 'Judy',
        'familyName' => 'Viancourt',
        'additionalName' => 'E',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  11 => 
  array (
    '@context' => 'http://schema.org',
    '@type' => 'Person',
    'name' => 'Anthony Russell Dalesio',
    'givenName' => 'Anthony',
    'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
    'additionalName' => 'Russell',
    'URL' => '/name/Anthony-Russell-Dalesio/Youngstown-OH/PG9RJnOdew9',
    'homeLocation' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Place',
        'address' => 
        array (
          '@type' => 'PostalAddress',
          'addressLocality' => 'Youngstown',
          'addressRegion' => 'OH',
          'addressCountry' => 'US',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'telephone' => '(330) XXX-XXXX',
    'relatedTo' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Suzanne R Dalesio',
        'givenName' => 'Suzanne',
        'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
        'additionalName' => 'R',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Vincent W Dalesio',
        'givenName' => 'Vincent',
        'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
        'additionalName' => 'W',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Nicholas P Dalesio',
        'givenName' => 'Nicholas',
        'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
        'additionalName' => 'P',
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Sophia M D Dalesio',
        'givenName' => 'Sophia',
        'familyName' => 'Dalesio',
        'additionalName' => 'M D',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  12 => 
  array (
    '@context' => 'http://schema.org',
    '@type' => 'Person',
    'name' => 'Antonio T Daloisio',
    'givenName' => 'Antonio',
    'familyName' => 'Daloisio',
    'additionalName' => 'T',
    'URL' => '/name/Antonio-T-Daloisio/Tuckahoe-NY/P53WWaQGR3G',
    'homeLocation' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Place',
        'address' => 
        array (
          '@type' => 'PostalAddress',
          'addressLocality' => 'Tuckahoe',
          'addressRegion' => 'NY',
          'addressCountry' => 'US',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'telephone' => '(914) XXX-XXXX',
    'relatedTo' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Giuseppe R Daloisio',
        'givenName' => 'Giuseppe',
        'familyName' => 'Daloisio',
        'additionalName' => 'R',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Clementina D Daloisio',
        'givenName' => 'Clementina',
        'familyName' => 'Daloisio',
        'additionalName' => 'D',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Clementina D Daloisio',
        'givenName' => 'Clementina',
        'familyName' => 'Daloisio',
        'additionalName' => 'D',
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Virgilio D Aloisio',
        'givenName' => 'Virgilio',
        'familyName' => 'Aloisio',
        'additionalName' => 'D',
      ),
      4 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Nicole Ret Oliva',
        'givenName' => 'Nicole',
        'familyName' => 'Oliva',
        'additionalName' => 'Ret',
      ),
    ),
  ),
  13 => 
  array (
    '@context' => 'http://schema.org',
    '@type' => 'Person',
    'name' => 'Antonio Daloisio',
    'givenName' => 'Antonio',
    'familyName' => 'Daloisio',
    'additionalName' => NULL,
    'URL' => '/name/Antonio-Daloisio/Yonkers-NY/Pg3bLXllAd9',
    'homeLocation' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Place',
        'address' => 
        array (
          '@type' => 'PostalAddress',
          'addressLocality' => 'Yonkers',
          'addressRegion' => 'NY',
          'addressCountry' => 'US',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'telephone' => '(914) XXX-XXXX',
    'relatedTo' => 
    array (
    ),
  ),
  14 => 
  array (
    '@context' => 'http://schema.org',
    '@type' => 'Person',
    'name' => 'Antonio Salvatore Daloisio',
    'givenName' => 'Antonio',
    'familyName' => 'Daloisio',
    'additionalName' => 'Salvatore',
    'URL' => '/name/Antonio-Salvatore-Daloisio/Manahawkin-NJ/PX3vL0O7L9k',
    'homeLocation' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Place',
        'address' => 
        array (
          '@type' => 'PostalAddress',
          'addressLocality' => 'Manahawkin',
          'addressRegion' => 'NJ',
          'addressCountry' => 'US',
        ),
      ),
    ),
    'telephone' => '(609) XXX-XXXX',
    'relatedTo' => 
    array (
      0 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Sabrina A Daloisio',
        'givenName' => 'Sabrina',
        'familyName' => 'Daloisio',
        'additionalName' => 'A',
      ),
      1 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Maria D Daloisio',
        'givenName' => 'Maria',
        'familyName' => 'Daloisio',
        'additionalName' => 'D',
      ),
      2 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Victoria A Daloisio',
        'givenName' => 'Victoria',
        'familyName' => 'Daloisio',
        'additionalName' => 'A',
      ),
      3 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Danielle A Daloisio',
        'givenName' => 'Danielle',
        'familyName' => 'Daloisio',
        'additionalName' => 'A',
      ),
      4 => 
      array (
        '@type' => 'Person',
        'name' => 'Philip Lorenzo Daloisio',
        'givenName' => 'Philip',
        'familyName' => 'Daloisio',
        'additionalName' => 'Lorenzo',
      ),
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: i receive the following error: RuntimeException: Chrome process stopped before startup completed. Additional info: sh: line 0: exec: chromium-browser: not found in

Comment: @daniele on some systems, chromium is invoked with `chromium-browser`, on some systems it's simply `chromium`, and on Windows I use ```C:\\Program Files\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe``` - i have [tried to improve](https://github.com/chrome-php/chrome/pull/597) the autodetect routine, but they haven't accepted my pull request (yet?) - regardless, replace `chromium-browser` with wherever your Chrome or Chromium installation is

Comment: I am under Windows , now i receive the following error: Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: implode(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type ?array, string given in C:\xampp\htdocs\paginebianche-canada-client\chrome\vendor\wrench\wrench\lib\Wrench\Protocol\Protocol.php:316

Do i have to install also Google Chrome from Google?

Comment: @daniele ouch yeah, that happens when you try to install the chrome-php library without the php-socket extension. add `extension=sockets` to your PHP.ini and run `php composer.phar update` - should fix it

Comment: @daniele well.. idk what composer is called on your system, but run `composer update` - on some systems its called `composer` , on other systems its called `composer.phar`

Comment: @hanshenrikd done, but now i receive the following error : Fatal error: Uncaught Wrench\Exception\HandshakeException: No accept header receieved on handshake response in C:\xampp\htdocs\paginebianche-canada-client\chrome\vendor\wrench\wrench\lib\Wrench\Protocol\Protocol.php:417

Comment: @daniele hmm that is a strange one.. are you running php older than 7.4.15?

Comment: NO! php -v  
PHP 8.2.12 (cli) (built: Oct 24 2023 21:15:15) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)

Comment: do i have to install Google Chrome in my windows ?

Comment: @daniele i recall a similar issue when trying to start chrome as a system-service on Windows. are you running xampp as a system service? if it's easy to convert your xampp from a system-service to a normal admin program, you can try that. otherwise, i suggest asking on the chrome-php bugtracker. and yes, you need either Chrome or [Chromium](https://download-chromium.appspot.com/)

Comment: i have launched Xampp ad administrator and installed Chromium but i always get the error :
`Fatal error: Uncaught Wrench\Exception\HandshakeException: No accept header receieved on handshake response in C:\xampp\htdocs\paginebianche-canada-client\chrome\vendor\wrench\wrench\lib\Wrench\Protocol\Protocol.php:417`