# How to get exact browser name and version?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, browser

I have tried some solutions but I am unable to get exact name and version:

**I am trying following code:**

```
$browserAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
echo $browserAgent;
```

**Output of above code:**

```
Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686) AppleWebKit/534.24 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/11.0.696.68 Safari/534.24
```

**But I am using:**

```
Google Chrome 11.0.696.68
on   
Ubuntu 10.04
```

So I can find in `Chrome/11.0.696.68` in output string but it is also showing some other browsers names that is confusing to extract exact browser **name/version** from string.

Comment: regarding the OS see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/647969/detect-exact-os-version-from-browser

Comment: and for the rest, this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457380/is-there-an-online-user-agent-database

Comment: There are a lot of good UserAgent parsers around. You can try one of the parser listed here https://github.com/ThaDafinser/UserAgentParser

Comment: Make sure you have browscap.ini file accessible through php.ini for any of the suggested solutions to work properly. Check the notes at: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php#101125

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Use [**`get_browser()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php#101125)

From Manual:

```
echo $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] . "\n\n";

$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
```

Will return:

```
Array
(
    [browser_name_regex] => ^mozilla/5\.0 (windows; .; windows nt 5\.1; .*rv:.*) gecko/.* firefox/0\.9.*$
    [browser_name_pattern] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; ?; Windows NT 5.1; *rv:*) Gecko/* Firefox/0.9*/
    [parent] => Firefox 0.9
    [platform] => WinXP
    [browser] => Firefox
    [version] => 0.9
    [majorver] => 0
    [minorver] => 9
    [cssversion] => 2
    [frames] => 1
    [iframes] => 1
    [tables] => 1
    [cookies] => 1
    [backgroundsounds] =>
    [vbscript] =>
    [javascript] => 1
    [javaapplets] => 1
    [activexcontrols] =>
    [cdf] =>
    [aol] =>
    [beta] => 1
    [win16] =>
    [crawler] =>
    [stripper] =>
    [wap] =>
    [netclr] =>
)
```

Comment: You need browscap.ini for this to work. *browscap.ini is not bundled with PHP ... it relies on user updates to keep the database current.* Which makes its usage troublesome.

Comment: Remember, that `get_browser` uses the browsercap.ini, which is an fat file with currently >2MByte. Using this function results in processing that big content, which could result in broken scripts, if you use that function multiple times in one script.

Comment: maybe you can use this $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] this is a constant magic in PHP

Answer (score 52):

Got an **awesome** function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php#101125).

```
<?php
function getBrowser() { 
  $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
  $bname = 'Unknown';
  $platform = 'Unknown';
  $version= "";

  //First get the platform?
  if (preg_match('/linux/i', $u_agent)) {
    $platform = 'linux';
  }elseif (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/i', $u_agent)) {
    $platform = 'mac';
  }elseif (preg_match('/windows|win32/i', $u_agent)) {
    $platform = 'windows';
  }

  // Next get the name of the useragent yes seperately and for good reason
  if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent)){
    $bname = 'Internet Explorer';
    $ub = "MSIE";
  }elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent)){
    $bname = 'Mozilla Firefox';
    $ub = "Firefox";
  }elseif(preg_match('/OPR/i',$u_agent)){
    $bname = 'Opera';
    $ub = "Opera";
  }elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Edge/i',$u_agent)){
    $bname = 'Google Chrome';
    $ub = "Chrome";
  }elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Edge/i',$u_agent)){
    $bname = 'Apple Safari';
    $ub = "Safari";
  }elseif(preg_match('/Netscape/i',$u_agent)){
    $bname = 'Netscape';
    $ub = "Netscape";
  }elseif(preg_match('/Edge/i',$u_agent)){
    $bname = 'Edge';
    $ub = "Edge";
  }elseif(preg_match('/Trident/i',$u_agent)){
    $bname = 'Internet Explorer';
    $ub = "MSIE";
  }

  // finally get the correct version number
  $known = array('Version', $ub, 'other');
  $pattern = '#(?<browser>' . join('|', $known) .
')[/ ]+(?<version>[0-9.|a-zA-Z.]*)#';
  if (!preg_match_all($pattern, $u_agent, $matches)) {
    // we have no matching number just continue
  }
  // see how many we have
  $i = count($matches['browser']);
  if ($i != 1) {
    //we will have two since we are not using 'other' argument yet
    //see if version is before or after the name
    if (strripos($u_agent,"Version") < strripos($u_agent,$ub)){
        $version= $matches['version'][0];
    }else {
        $version= $matches['version'][1];
    }
  }else {
    $version= $matches['version'][0];
  }

  // check if we have a number
  if ($version==null || $version=="") {$version="?";}

  return array(
    'userAgent' => $u_agent,
    'name'      => $bname,
    'version'   => $version,
    'platform'  => $platform,
    'pattern'    => $pattern
  );
} 

// now try it
$ua=getBrowser();
$yourbrowser= "Your browser: " . $ua['name'] . " " . $ua['version'] . " on " .$ua['platform'] . " reports: <br >" . $ua['userAgent'];
print_r($yourbrowser);
?>
```

Answer (score 47):

this JavaScript give you the browser name and the version,

```
var browser = '';
var browserVersion = 0;

if (/Opera[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    browser = 'Opera';
} else if (/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    browser = 'MSIE';
} else if (/Navigator[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    browser = 'Netscape';
} else if (/Chrome[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    browser = 'Chrome';
} else if (/Safari[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    browser = 'Safari';
    /Version[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent);
    browserVersion = new Number(RegExp.$1);
} else if (/Firefox[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    browser = 'Firefox';
}
if(browserVersion === 0){
    browserVersion = parseFloat(new Number(RegExp.$1));
}
alert(browser + "*" + browserVersion);
```

Comment: any reason for downvote? if the reason is, this is not PHP, did you see he mentioned PHP in the question? if he only want to get PHP answers why question is tag to the JavaScript and jQuery?

Comment: +1 Answer in jQuery and JavaScript are also acceptable. That is why I added these tags.

Comment: Can you test the script in 2015. with IE its showing nothing.

Comment: In 2019, Edge and opera will return = Chrome

Comment: @webchun I think it's because Edge uses Chromium

Comment: I think a complete and precise answer should return Edge and Opera in  Edge and Opera, not Chrome, like Some other codes on this page. I am right?

Answer (score 29):

I would like to suggest you this amazing class. This worked very well for me.

[http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php.html/](http://chrisschuld.com/projects/browser-php-detecting-a-users-browser-from-php.html)

I am publishing the code I used with the copyright notice of original author. You can get latest code from the link above.

```
<?php
/**
 * File: Browser.php
 * Author: Chris Schuld (http://chrisschuld.com/)
 *
 * Copyright (C) 2008-2010 Chris Schuld  (chris@chrisschuld.com)
 *
 * Typical Usage:
 *
 *   $browser = new Browser();
 *   if( $browser->getBrowser() == Browser::BROWSER_FIREFOX && $browser->getVersion() >= 2 ) {
 *      echo 'You have FireFox version 2 or greater';
 *   }
 *
*/

class Browser {
    private $_agent = '';
    private $_browser_name = '';
    private $_version = '';
    private $_platform = '';
    private $_os = '';
    private $_is_aol = false;
    private $_is_mobile = false;
    private $_is_robot = false;
    private $_aol_version = '';

    const BROWSER_UNKNOWN = 'unknown';
    const VERSION_UNKNOWN = 'unknown';

    const BROWSER_OPERA = 'Opera'; 
    const BROWSER_OPERA_MINI = 'Opera Mini';
    const BROWSER_WEBTV = 'WebTV';
    const BROWSER_IE = 'Internet Explorer'; 
    const BROWSER_POCKET_IE = 'Pocket Internet Explorer';
    const BROWSER_KONQUEROR = 'Konqueror';
    const BROWSER_ICAB = 'iCab';
    const BROWSER_OMNIWEB = 'OmniWeb';
    const BROWSER_FIREBIRD = 'Firebird';
    const BROWSER_FIREFOX = 'Firefox';
    const BROWSER_ICEWEASEL = 'Iceweasel';
    const BROWSER_SHIRETOKO = 'Shiretoko';
    const BROWSER_MOZILLA = 'Mozilla';
    const BROWSER_AMAYA = 'Amaya';
    const BROWSER_LYNX = 'Lynx';
    const BROWSER_SAFARI = 'Safari';
    const BROWSER_IPHONE = 'iPhone';
    const BROWSER_IPOD = 'iPod';
    const BROWSER_IPAD = 'iPad';
    const BROWSER_CHROME = 'Chrome';
    const BROWSER_ANDROID = 'Android';
    const BROWSER_GOOGLEBOT = 'GoogleBot';
    const BROWSER_SLURP = 'Yahoo! Slurp';
    const BROWSER_W3CVALIDATOR = 'W3C Validator';
    const BROWSER_BLACKBERRY = 'BlackBerry';
    const BROWSER_ICECAT = 'IceCat';
    const BROWSER_NOKIA_S60 = 'Nokia S60 OSS Browser';
    const BROWSER_NOKIA = 'Nokia Browser';
    const BROWSER_MSN = 'MSN Browser';
    const BROWSER_MSNBOT = 'MSN Bot';

    const BROWSER_NETSCAPE_NAVIGATOR = 'Netscape Navigator';
    const BROWSER_GALEON = 'Galeon';
    const BROWSER_NETPOSITIVE = 'NetPositive';
    const BROWSER_PHOENIX = 'Phoenix';

    const PLATFORM_UNKNOWN = 'unknown';
    const PLATFORM_WINDOWS = 'Windows';
    const PLATFORM_WINDOWS_CE = 'Windows CE';
    const PLATFORM_APPLE = 'Apple';
    const PLATFORM_LINUX = 'Linux';
    const PLATFORM_OS2 = 'OS/2';
    const PLATFORM_BEOS = 'BeOS';
    const PLATFORM_IPHONE = 'iPhone';
    const PLATFORM_IPOD = 'iPod';
    const PLATFORM_IPAD = 'iPad';
    const PLATFORM_BLACKBERRY = 'BlackBerry';
    const PLATFORM_NOKIA = 'Nokia';
    const PLATFORM_FREEBSD = 'FreeBSD';
    const PLATFORM_OPENBSD = 'OpenBSD';
    const PLATFORM_NETBSD = 'NetBSD';
    const PLATFORM_SUNOS = 'SunOS';
    const PLATFORM_OPENSOLARIS = 'OpenSolaris';
    const PLATFORM_ANDROID = 'Android';

    const OPERATING_SYSTEM_UNKNOWN = 'unknown';

    public function Browser($useragent="") {
        $this->reset();
        if( $useragent != "" ) {
            $this->setUserAgent($useragent);
        }
        else {
            $this->determine();
        }
    }

    /**
    * Reset all properties
    */
    public function reset() {
        $this->_agent = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : "";
        $this->_browser_name = self::BROWSER_UNKNOWN;
        $this->_version = self::VERSION_UNKNOWN;
        $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_UNKNOWN;
        $this->_os = self::OPERATING_SYSTEM_UNKNOWN;
        $this->_is_aol = false;
        $this->_is_mobile = false;
        $this->_is_robot = false;
        $this->_aol_version = self::VERSION_UNKNOWN;
    }

    /**
    * Check to see if the specific browser is valid
    * @param string $browserName
    * @return boolean
    */
    function isBrowser($browserName) { return( 0 == strcasecmp($this->_browser_name, trim($browserName))); }

    /**
    * The name of the browser.  All return types are from the class contants
    * @return string Name of the browser
    */
    public function getBrowser() { return $this->_browser_name; }
    /**
    * Set the name of the browser
    * @param $browser The name of the Browser
    */
    public function setBrowser($browser) { return $this->_browser_name = $browser; }
    /**
    * The name of the platform.  All return types are from the class contants
    * @return string Name of the browser
    */
    public function getPlatform() { return $this->_platform; }
    /**
    * Set the name of the platform
    * @param $platform The name of the Platform
    */
    public function setPlatform($platform) { return $this->_platform = $platform; }
    /**
    * The version of the browser.
    * @return string Version of the browser (will only contain alpha-numeric characters and a period)
    */
    public function getVersion() { return $this->_version; }
    /**
    * Set the version of the browser
    * @param $version The version of the Browser
    */
    public function setVersion($version) { $this->_version = preg_replace('/[^0-9,.,a-z,A-Z-]/','',$version); }
    /**
    * The version of AOL.
    * @return string Version of AOL (will only contain alpha-numeric characters and a period)
    */
    public function getAolVersion() { return $this->_aol_version; }
    /**
    * Set the version of AOL
    * @param $version The version of AOL
    */
    public function setAolVersion($version) { $this->_aol_version = preg_replace('/[^0-9,.,a-z,A-Z]/','',$version); }
    /**
    * Is the browser from AOL?
    * @return boolean
    */
    public function isAol() { return $this->_is_aol; }
    /**
    * Is the browser from a mobile device?
    * @return boolean
    */
    public function isMobile() { return $this->_is_mobile; }
    /**
    * Is the browser from a robot (ex Slurp,GoogleBot)?
    * @return boolean
    */
    public function isRobot() { return $this->_is_robot; }
    /**
    * Set the browser to be from AOL
    * @param $isAol
    */
    public function setAol($isAol) { $this->_is_aol = $isAol; }
    /**
     * Set the Browser to be mobile
     * @param boolean
     */
    protected function setMobile($value=true) { $this->_is_mobile = $value; }
    /**
     * Set the Browser to be a robot
     * @param boolean
     */
    protected function setRobot($value=true) { $this->_is_robot = $value; }
    /**
    * Get the user agent value in use to determine the browser
    * @return string The user agent from the HTTP header
    */
    public function getUserAgent() { return $this->_agent; }
    /**
    * Set the user agent value (the construction will use the HTTP header value - this will overwrite it)
    * @param $agent_string The value for the User Agent
    */
    public function setUserAgent($agent_string) {
        $this->reset();
        $this->_agent = $agent_string;
        $this->determine();
    }
    /**
     * Used to determine if the browser is actually "chromeframe"
     * @return boolean
     */
    public function isChromeFrame() {
        return( strpos($this->_agent,"chromeframe") !== false );
    }
    /**
    * Returns a formatted string with a summary of the details of the browser.
    * @return string formatted string with a summary of the browser
    */
    public function __toString() {
        return "<strong>Browser Name:</strong>{$this->getBrowser()}<br/>\n" .
               "<strong>Browser Version:</strong>{$this->getVersion()}<br/>\n" .
               "<strong>Browser User Agent String:</strong>{$this->getUserAgent()}<br/>\n" .
               "<strong>Platform:</strong>{$this->getPlatform()}<br/>";
    }
    /**
     * Protected routine to calculate and determine what the browser is in use (including platform)
     */
    protected function determine() {
        $this->checkPlatform();
        $this->checkBrowsers();
        $this->checkForAol();
    }
    /**
     * Protected routine to determine the browser type
     * @return boolean
     */
     protected function checkBrowsers() {
        return (
            $this->checkBrowserWebTv() ||
            $this->checkBrowserInternetExplorer() ||
            $this->checkBrowserOpera() ||
            $this->checkBrowserGaleon() ||
            $this->checkBrowserNetscapeNavigator9Plus() ||
            $this->checkBrowserFirefox() ||
            $this->checkBrowserChrome() ||
            $this->checkBrowserOmniWeb() ||

            // common mobile
            $this->checkBrowserAndroid() ||
            $this->checkBrowseriPad() ||
            $this->checkBrowseriPod() ||
            $this->checkBrowseriPhone() ||
            $this->checkBrowserBlackBerry() ||
            $this->checkBrowserNokia() ||

            // common bots
            $this->checkBrowserGoogleBot() ||
            $this->checkBrowserMSNBot() ||
            $this->checkBrowserSlurp() ||

            // WebKit base check (post mobile and others)
            $this->checkBrowserSafari() ||

            // everyone else
            $this->checkBrowserNetPositive() ||
            $this->checkBrowserFirebird() ||
            $this->checkBrowserKonqueror() ||
            $this->checkBrowserIcab() ||
            $this->checkBrowserPhoenix() ||
            $this->checkBrowserAmaya() ||
            $this->checkBrowserLynx() ||
            $this->checkBrowserShiretoko() ||
            $this->checkBrowserIceCat() ||
            $this->checkBrowserW3CValidator() ||
            $this->checkBrowserMozilla() /* Mozilla is such an open standard that you must check it last */
        );
    }

    protected function checkBrowserBlackBerry() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'blackberry') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode("/",stristr($this->_agent,"BlackBerry"));
            $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
            $this->setVersion($aversion[0]);
            $this->_browser_name = self::BROWSER_BLACKBERRY;
            $this->setMobile(true);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected function checkForAol() {
        $this->setAol(false);
        $this->setAolVersion(self::VERSION_UNKNOWN);

        if( stripos($this->_agent,'aol') !== false ) {
            $aversion = explode(' ',stristr($this->_agent, 'AOL'));
            $this->setAol(true);
            $this->setAolVersion(preg_replace('/[^0-9\.a-z]/i', '', $aversion[1]));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    protected function checkBrowserGoogleBot() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'googlebot') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode('/',stristr($this->_agent,'googlebot'));
            $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
            $this->setVersion(str_replace(';','',$aversion[0]));
            $this->_browser_name = self::BROWSER_GOOGLEBOT;
            $this->setRobot(true);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected function checkBrowserMSNBot() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,"msnbot") !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode("/",stristr($this->_agent,"msnbot"));
            $aversion = explode(" ",$aresult[1]);
            $this->setVersion(str_replace(";","",$aversion[0]));
            $this->_browser_name = self::BROWSER_MSNBOT;
            $this->setRobot(true);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }       

    protected function checkBrowserW3CValidator() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'W3C-checklink') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode('/',stristr($this->_agent,'W3C-checklink'));
            $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
            $this->setVersion($aversion[0]);
            $this->_browser_name = self::BROWSER_W3CVALIDATOR;
            return true;
        }
        else if( stripos($this->_agent,'W3C_Validator') !== false ) {
            // Some of the Validator versions do not delineate w/ a slash - add it back in
            $ua = str_replace("W3C_Validator ", "W3C_Validator/", $this->_agent);
            $aresult = explode('/',stristr($ua,'W3C_Validator'));
            $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
            $this->setVersion($aversion[0]);
            $this->_browser_name = self::BROWSER_W3CVALIDATOR;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected function checkBrowserSlurp() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'slurp') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode('/',stristr($this->_agent,'Slurp'));
            $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
            $this->setVersion($aversion[0]);
            $this->_browser_name = self::BROWSER_SLURP;
            $this->setRobot(true);
            $this->setMobile(false);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected function checkBrowserInternetExplorer() {

        // Test for v1 - v1.5 IE
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'microsoft internet explorer') !== false ) {
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_IE);
            $this->setVersion('1.0');
            $aresult = stristr($this->_agent, '/');
            if( preg_match('/308|425|426|474|0b1/i', $aresult) ) {
                $this->setVersion('1.5');
            }
            return true;
        }
        // Test for versions > 1.5
        else if( stripos($this->_agent,'msie') !== false && stripos($this->_agent,'opera') === false ) {
            // See if the browser is the odd MSN Explorer
            if( stripos($this->_agent,'msnb') !== false ) {
                $aresult = explode(' ',stristr(str_replace(';','; ',$this->_agent),'MSN'));
                $this->setBrowser( self::BROWSER_MSN );
                $this->setVersion(str_replace(array('(',')',';'),'',$aresult[1]));
                return true;
            }
            $aresult = explode(' ',stristr(str_replace(';','; ',$this->_agent),'msie'));
            $this->setBrowser( self::BROWSER_IE );
            $this->setVersion(str_replace(array('(',')',';'),'',$aresult[1]));
            return true;
        }
        // Test for Pocket IE
        else if( stripos($this->_agent,'mspie') !== false || stripos($this->_agent,'pocket') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode(' ',stristr($this->_agent,'mspie'));
            $this->setPlatform( self::PLATFORM_WINDOWS_CE );
            $this->setBrowser( self::BROWSER_POCKET_IE );
            $this->setMobile(true);

            if( stripos($this->_agent,'mspie') !== false ) {
                $this->setVersion($aresult[1]);
            }
            else {
                $aversion = explode('/',$this->_agent);
                $this->setVersion($aversion[1]);
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected function checkBrowserOpera() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'opera mini') !== false ) {
            $resultant = stristr($this->_agent, 'opera mini');
            if( preg_match('/\//',$resultant) ) {
                $aresult = explode('/',$resultant);
                $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
                $this->setVersion($aversion[0]);
            }
            else {
                $aversion = explode(' ',stristr($resultant,'opera mini'));
                $this->setVersion($aversion[1]);
            }
            $this->_browser_name = self::BROWSER_OPERA_MINI;
            $this->setMobile(true);
            return true;
        }
        else if( stripos($this->_agent,'opera') !== false ) {
            $resultant = stristr($this->_agent, 'opera');
            if( preg_match('/Version\/(10.*)$/',$resultant,$matches) ) {
                $this->setVersion($matches[1]);
            }
            else if( preg_match('/\//',$resultant) ) {
                $aresult = explode('/',str_replace("("," ",$resultant));
                $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
                $this->setVersion($aversion[0]);
            }
            else {
                $aversion = explode(' ',stristr($resultant,'opera'));
                $this->setVersion(isset($aversion[1])?$aversion[1]:"");
            }
            $this->_browser_name = self::BROWSER_OPERA;
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


    protected function checkBrowserChrome() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'Chrome') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode('/',stristr($this->_agent,'Chrome'));
            $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
            $this->setVersion($aversion[0]);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_CHROME);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected function checkBrowserWebTv() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'webtv') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode('/',stristr($this->_agent,'webtv'));
            $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
            $this->setVersion($aversion[0]);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_WEBTV);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected function checkBrowserNetPositive() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'NetPositive') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode('/',stristr($this->_agent,'NetPositive'));
            $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
            $this->setVersion(str_replace(array('(',')',';'),'',$aversion[0]));
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_NETPOSITIVE);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected function checkBrowserGaleon() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'galeon') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode(' ',stristr($this->_agent,'galeon'));
            $aversion = explode('/',$aresult[0]);
            $this->setVersion($aversion[1]);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_GALEON);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected function checkBrowserKonqueror() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'Konqueror') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode(' ',stristr($this->_agent,'Konqueror'));
            $aversion = explode('/',$aresult[0]);
            $this->setVersion($aversion[1]);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_KONQUEROR);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected function checkBrowserIcab() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'icab') !== false ) {
            $aversion = explode(' ',stristr(str_replace('/',' ',$this->_agent),'icab'));
            $this->setVersion($aversion[1]);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_ICAB);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected function checkBrowserOmniWeb() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'omniweb') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode('/',stristr($this->_agent,'omniweb'));
            $aversion = explode(' ',isset($aresult[1])?$aresult[1]:"");
            $this->setVersion($aversion[0]);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_OMNIWEB);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected function checkBrowserPhoenix() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'Phoenix') !== false ) {
            $aversion = explode('/',stristr($this->_agent,'Phoenix'));
            $this->setVersion($aversion[1]);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_PHOENIX);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected function checkBrowserFirebird() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'Firebird') !== false ) {
            $aversion = explode('/',stristr($this->_agent,'Firebird'));
            $this->setVersion($aversion[1]);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_FIREBIRD);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected function checkBrowserNetscapeNavigator9Plus() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'Firefox') !== false && preg_match('/Navigator\/([^ ]*)/i',$this->_agent,$matches) ) {
            $this->setVersion($matches[1]);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_NETSCAPE_NAVIGATOR);
            return true;
        }
        else if( stripos($this->_agent,'Firefox') === false && preg_match('/Netscape6?\/([^ ]*)/i',$this->_agent,$matches) ) {
            $this->setVersion($matches[1]);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_NETSCAPE_NAVIGATOR);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected function checkBrowserShiretoko() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'Mozilla') !== false && preg_match('/Shiretoko\/([^ ]*)/i',$this->_agent,$matches) ) {
            $this->setVersion($matches[1]);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_SHIRETOKO);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected function checkBrowserIceCat() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'Mozilla') !== false && preg_match('/IceCat\/([^ ]*)/i',$this->_agent,$matches) ) {
            $this->setVersion($matches[1]);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_ICECAT);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected function checkBrowserNokia() {
        if( preg_match("/Nokia([^\/]+)\/([^ SP]+)/i",$this->_agent,$matches) ) {
            $this->setVersion($matches[2]);
            if( stripos($this->_agent,'Series60') !== false || strpos($this->_agent,'S60') !== false ) {
                $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_NOKIA_S60);
            }
            else {
                $this->setBrowser( self::BROWSER_NOKIA );
            }
            $this->setMobile(true);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected function checkBrowserFirefox() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'safari') === false ) {
            if( preg_match("/Firefox[\/ \(]([^ ;\)]+)/i",$this->_agent,$matches) ) {
                $this->setVersion($matches[1]);
                $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_FIREFOX);
                return true;
            }
            else if( preg_match("/Firefox$/i",$this->_agent,$matches) ) {
                $this->setVersion("");
                $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_FIREFOX);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected function checkBrowserIceweasel() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'Iceweasel') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode('/',stristr($this->_agent,'Iceweasel'));
            $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
            $this->setVersion($aversion[0]);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_ICEWEASEL);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected function checkBrowserMozilla() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'mozilla') !== false  && preg_match('/rv:[0-9].[0-9][a-b]?/i',$this->_agent) && stripos($this->_agent,'netscape') === false) {
            $aversion = explode(' ',stristr($this->_agent,'rv:'));
            preg_match('/rv:[0-9].[0-9][a-b]?/i',$this->_agent,$aversion);
            $this->setVersion(str_replace('rv:','',$aversion[0]));
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_MOZILLA);
            return true;
        }
        else if( stripos($this->_agent,'mozilla') !== false && preg_match('/rv:[0-9]\.[0-9]/i',$this->_agent) && stripos($this->_agent,'netscape') === false ) {
            $aversion = explode('',stristr($this->_agent,'rv:'));
            $this->setVersion(str_replace('rv:','',$aversion[0]));
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_MOZILLA);
            return true;
        }
        else if( stripos($this->_agent,'mozilla') !== false  && preg_match('/mozilla\/([^ ]*)/i',$this->_agent,$matches) && stripos($this->_agent,'netscape') === false ) {
            $this->setVersion($matches[1]);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_MOZILLA);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected function checkBrowserLynx() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'lynx') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode('/',stristr($this->_agent,'Lynx'));
            $aversion = explode(' ',(isset($aresult[1])?$aresult[1]:""));
            $this->setVersion($aversion[0]);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_LYNX);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected function checkBrowserAmaya() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'amaya') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode('/',stristr($this->_agent,'Amaya'));
            $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
            $this->setVersion($aversion[0]);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_AMAYA);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected function checkBrowserSafari() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'Safari') !== false && stripos($this->_agent,'iPhone') === false && stripos($this->_agent,'iPod') === false ) {
            $aresult = explode('/',stristr($this->_agent,'Version'));
            if( isset($aresult[1]) ) {
                $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
                $this->setVersion($aversion[0]);
            }
            else {
                $this->setVersion(self::VERSION_UNKNOWN);
            }
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_SAFARI);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected function checkBrowseriPhone() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'iPhone') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode('/',stristr($this->_agent,'Version'));
            if( isset($aresult[1]) ) {
                $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
                $this->setVersion($aversion[0]);
            }
            else {
                $this->setVersion(self::VERSION_UNKNOWN);
            }
            $this->setMobile(true);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_IPHONE);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected function checkBrowseriPad() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'iPad') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode('/',stristr($this->_agent,'Version'));
            if( isset($aresult[1]) ) {
                $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
                $this->setVersion($aversion[0]);
            }
            else {
                $this->setVersion(self::VERSION_UNKNOWN);
            }
            $this->setMobile(true);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_IPAD);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected function checkBrowseriPod() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'iPod') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode('/',stristr($this->_agent,'Version'));
            if( isset($aresult[1]) ) {
                $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
                $this->setVersion($aversion[0]);
            }
            else {
                $this->setVersion(self::VERSION_UNKNOWN);
            }
            $this->setMobile(true);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_IPOD);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    protected function checkBrowserAndroid() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent,'Android') !== false ) {
            $aresult = explode(' ',stristr($this->_agent,'Android'));
            if( isset($aresult[1]) ) {
                $aversion = explode(' ',$aresult[1]);
                $this->setVersion($aversion[0]);
            }
            else {
                $this->setVersion(self::VERSION_UNKNOWN);
            }
            $this->setMobile(true);
            $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_ANDROID);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Determine the user's platform
     */
    protected function checkPlatform() {
        if( stripos($this->_agent, 'windows') !== false ) {
            $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_WINDOWS;
        }
        else if( stripos($this->_agent, 'iPad') !== false ) {
            $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_IPAD;
        }
        else if( stripos($this->_agent, 'iPod') !== false ) {
            $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_IPOD;
        }
        else if( stripos($this->_agent, 'iPhone') !== false ) {
            $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_IPHONE;
        }
        elseif( stripos($this->_agent, 'mac') !== false ) {
            $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_APPLE;
        }
        elseif( stripos($this->_agent, 'android') !== false ) {
            $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_ANDROID;
        }
        elseif( stripos($this->_agent, 'linux') !== false ) {
            $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_LINUX;
        }
        else if( stripos($this->_agent, 'Nokia') !== false ) {
            $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_NOKIA;
        }
        else if( stripos($this->_agent, 'BlackBerry') !== false ) {
            $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_BLACKBERRY;
        }
        elseif( stripos($this->_agent,'FreeBSD') !== false ) {
            $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_FREEBSD;
        }
        elseif( stripos($this->_agent,'OpenBSD') !== false ) {
            $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_OPENBSD;
        }
        elseif( stripos($this->_agent,'NetBSD') !== false ) {
            $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_NETBSD;
        }
        elseif( stripos($this->_agent, 'OpenSolaris') !== false ) {
            $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_OPENSOLARIS;
        }
        elseif( stripos($this->_agent, 'SunOS') !== false ) {
            $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_SUNOS;
        }
        elseif( stripos($this->_agent, 'OS\/2') !== false ) {
            $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_OS2;
        }
        elseif( stripos($this->_agent, 'BeOS') !== false ) {
            $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_BEOS;
        }
        elseif( stripos($this->_agent, 'win') !== false ) {
            $this->_platform = self::PLATFORM_WINDOWS;
        }

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: The class cannot detect IE11. In the beginning of `function checkBrowserInternetExplorer()` add: `if( stripos($this->_agent,'Trident/7.0; rv:11.0') !== false ) { $this->setBrowser(self::BROWSER_IE); $this->setVersion('11.0'); return true; } else if( ... `

Comment: A rewrite of that class is [available](https://github.com/Wolfcast/BrowserDetection). It support natively IE 11.

Answer (score 13):

I have created a function in PHP language to get browser name, browser version, operating system (windows/linux etc.) along with device type (desktop / mobile / tablet).

```
function getBrowserInfo(){
    $browserInfo = array('user_agent'=>'','browser'=>'','browser_version'=>'','os_platform'=>'','pattern'=>'', 'device'=>'');

    $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
    $bname = 'Unknown';
    $ub = 'Unknown';
    $version = "";
    $platform = 'Unknown';

    $deviceType='Desktop';

    if(preg_match('/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i',$u_agent)||preg_match('/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i',substr($u_agent,0,4))){

        $deviceType='Mobile';

    }

    if($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == 'Mozilla/5.0(iPad; U; CPU iPhone OS 3_2 like Mac OS X; en-us) AppleWebKit/531.21.10 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Mobile/7B314 Safari/531.21.10') {
        $deviceType='Tablet';
    }

    if(stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Mozilla/5.0(iPad;')) {
        $deviceType='Tablet';
    }

    //$detect = new Mobile_Detect();
    
    //First get the platform?
    if (preg_match('/linux/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'linux';

    } elseif (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'mac';

    } elseif (preg_match('/windows|win32/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'windows';
    }

    // Next get the name of the user agent yes seperately and for good reason
    if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'IE'; 
        $ub = "MSIE";

    } else if(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent))
    { 
        $bname = 'Mozilla Firefox'; 
        $ub = "Firefox"; 

    } else if(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent) && (!preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/OPR/i',$u_agent))) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Chrome'; 
        $ub = "Chrome"; 

    } else if(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent) && (!preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/OPR/i',$u_agent))) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Safari'; 
        $ub = "Safari"; 

    } else if(preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent) || preg_match('/OPR/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Opera'; 
        $ub = "Opera"; 

    } else if(preg_match('/Netscape/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Netscape'; 
        $ub = "Netscape"; 

    } else if((isset($u_agent) && (strpos($u_agent, 'Trident') !== false || strpos($u_agent, 'MSIE') !== false)))
    {
        $bname = 'Internet Explorer'; 
        $ub = 'Internet Explorer'; 
    } 
    

    // finally get the correct version number
    $known = array('Version', $ub, 'other');
    $pattern = '#(?<browser>' . join('|', $known) . ')[/ ]+(?<version>[0-9.|a-zA-Z.]*)#';

    if (!preg_match_all($pattern, $u_agent, $matches)) {
        // we have no matching number just continue
    }

    // see how many we have
    $i = count($matches['browser']);
    if ($i != 1) {
        //we will have two since we are not using 'other' argument yet
        //see if version is before or after the name
        if (strripos($u_agent,"Version") < strripos($u_agent,$ub)){
            $version= $matches['version'][0];

        } else {
            $version= @$matches['version'][1];
        }

    } else {
        $version= $matches['version'][0];
    }

    // check if we have a number
    if ($version==null || $version=="") {$version="?";}

    return array(
        'user_agent' => $u_agent,
        'browser'      => $bname,
        'browser_version'   => $version,
        'os_platform'  => $platform,
        'pattern'   => $pattern,
        'device'    => $deviceType
    );
}
```

This solved my problem of browser detection, I hope, this will also help you. Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

Use `get_browser()` [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php).

It can give you output like this:

```
Array
(
    [browser_name_regex] => ^mozilla/5\.0 (windows; .; windows nt 5\.1; .*rv:.*) gecko/.* firefox/0\.9.*$
    [browser_name_pattern] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; ?; Windows NT 5.1; *rv:*) Gecko/* Firefox/0.9*
    [parent] => Firefox 0.9
    [platform] => WinXP
    [browser] => Firefox
    [version] => 0.9
    [majorver] => 0
    [minorver] => 9
    ....
```

Comment: See these comments for why you might not want to use `get_browser()` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754080/how-to-get-exact-browser-name-and-version#comments-8754109

Answer (score 7):

- There is a conflict between (Safari) and (Opera) and (Chrome) !!!
- The above codes couldn't work properly

This is my code, and it works very well without any conflict:

```
function ExactBrowserName()
{

$ExactBrowserNameUA=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

if (strpos(strtolower($ExactBrowserNameUA), "safari/") and strpos(strtolower($ExactBrowserNameUA), "opr/")) {
    // OPERA
    $ExactBrowserNameBR="Opera";
} elseIf (strpos(strtolower($ExactBrowserNameUA), "safari/") and strpos(strtolower($ExactBrowserNameUA), "chrome/")) {
    // CHROME
    $ExactBrowserNameBR="Chrome";
} elseIf (strpos(strtolower($ExactBrowserNameUA), "msie")) {
    // INTERNET EXPLORER
    $ExactBrowserNameBR="Internet Explorer";
} elseIf (strpos(strtolower($ExactBrowserNameUA), "firefox/")) {
    // FIREFOX
    $ExactBrowserNameBR="Firefox";
} elseIf (strpos(strtolower($ExactBrowserNameUA), "safari/") and strpos(strtolower($ExactBrowserNameUA), "opr/")==false and strpos(strtolower($ExactBrowserNameUA), "chrome/")==false) {
    // SAFARI
    $ExactBrowserNameBR="Safari";
} else {
    // OUT OF DATA
    $ExactBrowserNameBR="OUT OF DATA";
};

return $ExactBrowserNameBR;
}
```

Comment: I modified this function, to follow PSR-2 standards and to detect IE11. [Here it is.](http://codepad.org/9nlGer9B) Sorry to rely on an external website, but comments' limits forced me to, and I do not believe it is a different solution. Tested with Opera, Chrome, Firefox and IE. I do not have Safari installed, sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Since some codes gave a wrong result for Edge and Opera, I suggest to try this code:

```
$popularBrowsers = ["Opera","OPR/", "Edg", "Chrome", "Safari", "Firefox", "MSIE", "Trident"];

$userAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
$userBrowser = 'Other less popular browsers';
foreach ($popularBrowsers as $browser) {
    if (strpos($userAgent, $browser) !== false) {
        $userBrowser = $browser;
        break;
    }
}

switch ($userBrowser) {
    case 'OPR/':
        $userBrowser = 'Opera';
        break;
    case 'MSIE':
        $userBrowser = 'Internet Explorer';
        break;

    case 'Trident':
        $userBrowser = 'Internet Explorer';
        break;

    case 'Edg':
        $userBrowser = 'Microsoft Edge';
        break;
}

echo "Your browser: " . $userBrowser;
```

For information about agent strings for different browsers and some similarities in them, please refer to: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent

Answer (score 0):

Use 51Degrees.com device detection solution to detect browser name, vendor and version.

First, follow the [4-step guide](http://51degrees.com/Support/Documentation/PHP/Getting-Started) to incorporate device detector in to your project. When I say incorporate I mean download archive with PHP code and database file, extract them and include 2 files. That's all there is to do to incorporate.

Once that's done you can use the following properties to get browser information:

[$_51d['BrowserName']](https://51degrees.com/Resources/Property-Dictionary#BrowserName) - Gives you the name of the browser (Safari, Molto, Motorola, MStarBrowser etc).

[$_51d['BrowserVendor']](https://51degrees.com/Resources/Property-Dictionary#BrowserVendor) - Gives you the company who created browser.

[$_51d['BrowserVersion']](https://51degrees.com/Resources/Property-Dictionary#BrowserVersion) - Version number of the browser

Answer (score 0):

Got this function [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php#101125) and updated. It works with Edge browser.

```
<?php
function getBrowser() 
{ 
    $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $bname = 'Unknown';
    $platform = 'Unknown';
    $version= "";

    //First get the platform?
    if (preg_match('/linux/i', $u_agent)) 
    {
        $platform = 'linux';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/i', $u_agent)) 
    {
        $platform = 'mac';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/windows|win32/i', $u_agent)) 
    {
        $platform = 'windows';
    }

    // Next get the name of the useragent yes seperately and for good reason
    if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Internet Explorer';
        $ub = "MSIE";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Mozilla Firefox';
        $ub = "Firefox";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/OPR/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Opera';
        $ub = "Opera";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Edg/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Google Chrome';
        $ub = "Chrome";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Edg/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Apple Safari';
        $ub = "Safari";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Netscape/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Netscape';
        $ub = "Netscape";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Edg/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Edge';
        $ub = "Edg";
    }
    elseif(preg_match('/Trident/i',$u_agent))
    {
        $bname = 'Internet Explorer';
        $ub = "MSIE";
    }

    // finally get the correct version number
    $known = array('Version', $ub, 'other');
    $pattern = '#(?<browser>' . join('|', $known) .     ')[/ ]+(?<version>[0-9.|a-zA-Z.]*)#';
    if (!preg_match_all($pattern, $u_agent, $matches))
   {
    // we have no matching number just continue
    }
    // see how many we have
    $i = count($matches['browser']);
    if ($i != 1)
    {
        //we will have two since we are not using 'other' argument yet
        //see if version is before or after the name
        if (strripos($u_agent,"Version") < strripos($u_agent,$ub))
        {
            $version= $matches['version'][0];
        }
        else 
        {
            $version= $matches['version'][1];
        }
    }else {
    $version= $matches['version'][0];
    }

    // check if we have a number
    if ($version==null || $version=="") 
    {
        $version="?";
    }

    return [
        'userAgent' => $u_agent,
        'name'      => $bname,
        'version'   => $version,
        'platform'  => $platform,
        'pattern'    => $pattern
    ];
} 

// invoke function
$arBrowser =  getBrowser();
echo '<pre>';
print_r($arBrowser);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```