# How to get the system's name, browsers name with version using php

Tags: php

I am creating a Registration system, I need to get the user's details such as system name, browser's name with version.

Most of the script I cross [How to get exact browser name and version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754080/how-to-get-exact-browser-name-and-version),

```
$browserAgent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
echo $browserAgent;
```

I am not getting the accurate result of the user's browser or its version, and I am not able to get the system's name. How can I do it ? Giving the direct code is appreciated than refering a link

Comment: what do you think you are detecting? if you want to know who people are an registration system is the only sound method

Comment: I edited my question to Registration system instead of Detecting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the User's System Name

```
<?php
echo 'Current script owner: ' . get_current_user();
?>
```

To get the User's Browser Name with version

```
<?php
function getBrowser() 
{ 
    $u_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 
    $bname = 'Unknown';
    $platform = 'Unknown';
    $version= "";

    //First get the platform?
    if (preg_match('/linux/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'linux';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'mac';
    }
    elseif (preg_match('/windows|win32/i', $u_agent)) {
        $platform = 'windows';
    }

    // Next get the name of the useragent yes seperately and for good reason
    if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$u_agent) && !preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Internet Explorer'; 
        $ub = "MSIE"; 
    } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Firefox/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Mozilla Firefox'; 
        $ub = "Firefox"; 
    } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Chrome/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Google Chrome'; 
        $ub = "Chrome"; 
    } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Safari/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Apple Safari'; 
        $ub = "Safari"; 
    } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Opera/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Opera'; 
        $ub = "Opera"; 
    } 
    elseif(preg_match('/Netscape/i',$u_agent)) 
    { 
        $bname = 'Netscape'; 
        $ub = "Netscape"; 
    } 

    // finally get the correct version number
    $known = array('Version', $ub, 'other');
    $pattern = '#(?<browser>' . join('|', $known) .
    ')[/ ]+(?<version>[0-9.|a-zA-Z.]*)#';
    if (!preg_match_all($pattern, $u_agent, $matches)) {
        // we have no matching number just continue
    }

    // see how many we have
    $i = count($matches['browser']);
    if ($i != 1) {
        //we will have two since we are not using 'other' argument yet
        //see if version is before or after the name
        if (strripos($u_agent,"Version") < strripos($u_agent,$ub)){
            $version= $matches['version'][0];
        }
        else {
            $version= $matches['version'][1];
        }
    }
    else {
        $version= $matches['version'][0];
    }

    // check if we have a number
    if ($version==null || $version=="") {$version="?";}

    return array(
        'userAgent' => $u_agent,
        'name'      => $bname,
        'version'   => $version,
        'platform'  => $platform,
        'pattern'    => $pattern
    );
} 

// now try it
$ua=getBrowser();
$yourbrowser= "Your browser: " . $ua['name'] . " " . $ua['version'] . " on " .$ua['platform'] . " reports: <br >" . $ua['userAgent'];
print_r($yourbrowser);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

$user_agent     =   $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

function getOS() { 

    global $user_agent;

    $os_platform    =   "Unknown OS Platform";

    $os_array       =   array(
                            '/windows nt 6.3/i'     =>  'Windows 8.1',
                            '/windows nt 6.2/i'     =>  'Windows 8',
                            '/windows nt 6.1/i'     =>  'Windows 7',
                            '/windows nt 6.0/i'     =>  'Windows Vista',
                            '/windows nt 5.2/i'     =>  'Windows Server 2003/XP x64',
                            '/windows nt 5.1/i'     =>  'Windows XP',
                            '/windows xp/i'         =>  'Windows XP',
                            '/windows nt 5.0/i'     =>  'Windows 2000',
                            '/windows me/i'         =>  'Windows ME',
                            '/win98/i'              =>  'Windows 98',
                            '/win95/i'              =>  'Windows 95',
                            '/win16/i'              =>  'Windows 3.11',
                            '/macintosh|mac os x/i' =>  'Mac OS X',
                            '/mac_powerpc/i'        =>  'Mac OS 9',
                            '/linux/i'              =>  'Linux',
                            '/ubuntu/i'             =>  'Ubuntu',
                            '/iphone/i'             =>  'iPhone',
                            '/ipod/i'               =>  'iPod',
                            '/ipad/i'               =>  'iPad',
                            '/android/i'            =>  'Android',
                            '/blackberry/i'         =>  'BlackBerry',
                            '/webos/i'              =>  'Mobile'
                        );

    foreach ($os_array as $regex => $value) { 

        if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent)) {
            $os_platform    =   $value;
        }

    }   

    return $os_platform;

}

function getBrowser() {

    global $user_agent;

    $browser        =   "Unknown Browser";

    $browser_array  =   array(
                            '/msie/i'       =>  'Internet Explorer',
                            '/firefox/i'    =>  'Firefox',
                            '/safari/i'     =>  'Safari',
                            '/chrome/i'     =>  'Chrome',
                            '/opera/i'      =>  'Opera',
                            '/netscape/i'   =>  'Netscape',
                            '/maxthon/i'    =>  'Maxthon',
                            '/konqueror/i'  =>  'Konqueror',
                            '/mobile/i'     =>  'Handheld Browser'
                        );

    foreach ($browser_array as $regex => $value) { 

        if (preg_match($regex, $user_agent)) {
            $browser    =   $value;
        }

    }

    return $browser;

}


$user_os        =   getOS();
$user_browser   =   getBrowser();

$device_details =   "<strong>Browser: </strong>".$user_browser."<br /><strong>Operating System: </strong>".$user_os."";

print_r($device_details);

echo("<br /><br /><br />".$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']."");

?>
```