# get_browser() returns Chrome when using Opera browser in Samsung galaxy tab

Tags: php, browscap

Hi Im tracking the browsers of the users who are visiting my site with the use of browsecap.ini

the following is the code that i use

```
if(isset($message['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
    $get_browser = get_browser($message['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], true);
       if (!empty($get_browser)){
           $str_values.='".mysql_real_escape_string($get_browser['comment'])."'
```

But when the users who use the opera browser in a galaxy tab are shown as chrome browser users

can anybody help me to rectify this isse

P.S - Im using the lite version of browsecap.ini file

Comment: any browsecap and php experts

Comment: Try manually entering a user-agent string that Opera on Galaxy would send and try to trace the array output that get_browser returns

Comment: i got it to an array it says chrome 41.0 in the browser... so no luck

Comment: Could you post the user-agent string you tried? I'd like to explore why this happening.

Comment: $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']

Comment: Yeah, hmm... okay, new approach: can you please echo out `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` or otherwise capture a _live_ user-agent string so we can investigate it?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76121/discussion-between-drakes-and-sho-gum-lew).

Comment: hi drakes i added the echo on chat

Answer (score 1):

You kindly provided me with a sample UA string of the offending mobile Opera browser:

> Mozilla/5.0 (Linux;￼ Android 4.1.2; GT-P3100 Build/JZO54K) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2272.81 Safari/537.36 OPR/28.0.1764.90386

and the regex returned by `get_browser()` on that UA is:

> $^mozilla/5.0 (.*linux.*android.4.1.*) applewebkit/.* (khtml, like gecko).*chrome/41..*safari/.*$

which didn't detect the Opera browser at all. However, I found this function that you can also run to get the browser name. The very first check is for that "*OPR/*" fragment of the UA string.

When run with the test UA supplied above, the output is "Opera".

```
<?php
function ExactBrowserName() {
    $ExactBrowserNameUA=$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];

    If (strpos(strtolower($ExactBrowserNameUA), "safari/") and strpos(strtolower($ExactBrowserNameUA), "opr/")) {
        // OPERA
        $ExactBrowserNameBR="Opera";
    } ElseIf (strpos(strtolower($ExactBrowserNameUA), "safari/") and strpos(strtolower($ExactBrowserNameUA), "chrome/")) {
        // CHROME
        $ExactBrowserNameBR="Chrome";
    } ElseIf (strpos(strtolower($ExactBrowserNameUA), "msie")) {
        // INTERNET EXPLORER
        $ExactBrowserNameBR="Internet Explorer";
    } ElseIf (strpos(strtolower($ExactBrowserNameUA), "firefox/")) {
        // FIREFOX
        $ExactBrowserNameBR="Firefox";
    } ElseIf (strpos(strtolower($ExactBrowserNameUA), "safari/") and strpos(strtolower($ExactBrowserNameUA), "opr/")==false and strpos(strtolower($ExactBrowserNameUA), "chrome/")==false) {
        // SAFARI
        $ExactBrowserNameBR="Safari";
    } Else {
        // OUT OF DATA
        $ExactBrowserNameBR="OUT OF DATA";
    };

    return $ExactBrowserNameBR;
}
?>
```

Ref: [How to get exact browser name and version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754080/how-to-get-exact-browser-name-and-version)