# php if statments to get the browser

Tags: php

Im trying to call a script if the browser is firefox and its working.
But now i want to do the same if the browser is Safari and im not being able to figure it out im missing the way that php works in if statments , im new to php.

```
<?php
function get_browser_name($user_agent)
{
    if (strpos($user_agent, 'Opera') || strpos($user_agent, 'OPR/')) return 'Opera';
    elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'Edge')) return 'Edge';
    elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'Chrome')) return 'Chrome';
    elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'Safari')) return 'Safari';
    elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'Firefox')) return 'Firefox';
    elseif (strpos($user_agent, 'MSIE') || strpos($user_agent, 'Trident/7')) return 'Internet Explorer';
   
    return 'Other';
}

$browser = get_browser_name($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

if($browser == "Firefox"): ?> do something here <?php endif; ?>
```

now i want to add an if for the Safari but im not seeing how i can do it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get exact browser name and version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8754080/how-to-get-exact-browser-name-and-version)

Comment: So `if($browser == 'Safari'): ?> do something here <?php endif; ?>` Completely excapes you?

Comment: if($browser == "Safari"): ?> do something not php here <?php endif; ?>